# How do I create an instance of a class that has a property with the type of another class?

Tags: c#, properties

Somebody could please be gentle to explain to me how to create an instance of the `Person` class, I'm having a hard time doing it. They are from separate archives, I just put them all together to make it more easily to view.

```
public class Person
{
       protected int id;
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public long Cpf { get; set; }
       public Telephone[] Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Telephone
{
       protected int id;
       public int Number { get; set; }
       public int Ddd { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
       Person p = new Person();
       p.Phones[0] = ??; 
}
```

Comment: `Phones` is an array. Do you know how to create a new array?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance in the same way you would any other, as you have done:

```
Person p = new Person();
```

You then have to allocate size to the array and instantiate it (I would suggest doing this somewhere within the person class, but it can be done from anywhere):

```
p.Phones = new Telephone[10];
```

The phones array now have 10 spaces available for Telephone instances.
If you want to access index 0 like in your example, you have to add it first:

```
p.Phones[0] = new Telephone();
```